# I am looking for a way to initialize an array in c header file

Tags: c

These are the contents of my max_subarray_data.h

```
#include<stdlib.h>

    int price[]={100,113,110,85,105,102,86,63,81,101,94,106,101,79,94,90,97};
    int n=(int)(sizeof(price)/sizeof(int))-1;
    int change[]={};
    for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)  **//here it is giving error-expected identifier or '('** 
         change[i]=price[i]-price[i-1];
```

I am looking for a way to resolve this !

Comment: heh? you're writing instruction outside a function? How?

Comment: Avoid code in header files! Stick to declaration of types, macro definitions and such ...

Comment: i want to calculate the change array here itself rather than calling it from the main.c file .

Comment: That needs to be inside a function, there is no way around it....

Comment: Where is "here"? It is floating in a vacuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put code outside of a function, and you shouldn't put a function definition inside of a header file.

max_subarray_data.h should contain the following:

```
extern int price[];
extern int change[];

void init_change();
```

Then create max_subarray_data.c which contains:

```
int price[]={100,113,110,85,105,102,86,63,81,101,94,106,101,79,94,90,97};
int change[(sizeof(price)/sizeof(int))-1];

void init_change() 
{
    int n=(int)(sizeof(price)/sizeof(int))-1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
         change[i-1]=price[i]-price[i-1];
    }
}
```

Then in your `main`, you need to call `init_change()` to initialize `change`.

EDIT:

Also, note that the loop now assigns to `change[i-1]` instead of `change[i]`, otherwise you'll be writing one element past the end of the array, and the first element will be uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks ! This helped.

Comment: @FibonacciCoder Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: The error has gone but i am still not getting the desired output.Will i have to ask it in a differnt question ?

Comment: @FibonacciCoder Yes, post it as a new question.  Be sure to post enough code so that others can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Well, it is allowed (and sensible) to have `static inline`  functions *defined* in header files.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How ?

Answer (score 1):

the best practice is to follow what @dbush did post. but if you insist, you can do macros initialization like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define PRICE_0         100
#define PRICE_1         113
#define PRICE_2         110
#define PRICE_3         85
#define PRICE_4         105
#define PRICE_5         102
#define PRICE_6         86
#define PRICE_7         63
#define PRICE_8         81
#define PRICE_9         101
#define PRICE_10        94
#define PRICE_11        106
#define PRICE_12        101
#define PRICE_13        79
#define PRICE_14        94
#define PRICE_15        90
#define PRICE_16        97

int price[]={
    PRICE_0,  // 0
    PRICE_1,  // 1
    PRICE_2,  // 2
    PRICE_3,   // 3
    PRICE_4,  // 4
    PRICE_5,  // 5
    PRICE_6,   // 6
    PRICE_7,   // 7
    PRICE_8,   // 8
    PRICE_9,  // 9
    PRICE_10,   // 10
    PRICE_11,  // 11
    PRICE_12,  // 12
    PRICE_13,   // 13
    PRICE_14,   // 14
    PRICE_15,   // 15
    PRICE_16};  // 16


#define PRICE_DIF(a,b)  (PRICE_ ## a - PRICE_ ## b)
int change[]={
    0,              // <-- what about this? :(
    PRICE_DIF(1,0),
    PRICE_DIF(2,1),
    PRICE_DIF(3,2),
    PRICE_DIF(4,3),
    PRICE_DIF(5,4),
    PRICE_DIF(6,5),
    PRICE_DIF(7,6),
    PRICE_DIF(8,7),
    PRICE_DIF(9,8),
    PRICE_DIF(10,9),
    PRICE_DIF(11,10),
    PRICE_DIF(12,11),
    PRICE_DIF(13,12),
    PRICE_DIF(14,13),
    PRICE_DIF(15,14),
    PRICE_DIF(16,15),

};



int main(void){
    for(int k=0;k<=17;k++)
         printf("%d\n",change[k]);

    return 0;
}
```